# In angular js How to do an edit option?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to do an edit field in angular js but I don't know how to do that one help me

below is my Crud operation code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = ["venu", "balaji", "suresh"];
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.errortext = "";
    if (!$scope.addMe) {
      return;
    }
    if ($scope.products.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
      $scope.products.push($scope.addMe)
    } else {
      $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your names list.";
    }
  }
  $scope.removeItem = function(x) {
    $scope.errortext = "";
    $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input ng-model="addMe">
    <button ng-click="addItem()">ADD</button>
    <p>{{errortext}}</p>
    <p>Try to add the same name twice, and you will get an error message.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am doing crud operations in angular js. i have done Delete and Add but I dont know how to do Edit operation in angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = ["venu", "balaji", "suresh"];
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.errortext = "";
    if (!$scope.addMe) {
      return;
    }
    if ($scope.products.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
      $scope.products.push($scope.addMe)
    } else {
      $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your names list.";
    }
    
    $scope.addMe = "";
  }
  $scope.removeItem = function(x) {
    $scope.errortext = "";
    $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
  }
  
  $scope.edit = function(index){
     $scope.addMe = $scope.products[index];
     $scope.products.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}
      <span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span>
      <span style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" ng-click="edit($index)">Edit</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input ng-model="addMe">
    <button ng-click="addItem()">ADD</button>
    <p>{{errortext}}</p>
    <p>Try to add the same name twice, and you will get an error message.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Comment: Your answer does not work if they cancel the edit as according to you when edit is clicked the item is removed from the array with $scope.products.splice(index, 1);

Comment: Its just an approach .You can always keep the deleted index in another variable for such edge conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="x in products" ng-click="preEdit(x, $index)">{{x}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span></li>
<input ng-model="addMe">
<button ng-if="isAdd" ng-click="addItem()">ADD</button>
<button ng-if="!isAdd" ng-click="editItem()">EDIT</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.isAdd = true;
$scope.preEdit = preEdit;
var index = '';
function preEdit(x, i){
     $scope.addMe = x;
     index = i;
     $scope.isAdd = false;
}
$scope.editItem = editItem ;
function editItem (){
     $scope.products[index] = $scope.addMe;
     $scope.isAdd = true;
     $scope.addMe = '';
     index = '';
}
```

Look my solution in filddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfx8njw6/

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to add a edit option on the `<li>` say,

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}
         <span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span> 
         <span ng-click="editItem($index)">Edit</span>

      </li>
</ul>
```

Then add a controller function for edit `editItem()` like

```
  $scope.editItem= function(index) {
    $scope.addMe = $scope.products[index];
    //this variable will allow you to check whether the operation is an edit or add
    $scope.editIndex = index;
  }
```

You can then reuse your `addItem()` function like this

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.errortext = "";
    if (!$scope.addMe) {
      return;
    }
    if(angular.isDefined($scope.editIndex)){
      $scope.products[$scope.editIndex] = $scope.addMe;
      //reset the variable to undefined after using it
      $scope.editIndex = undefined;
    }else{
       if ($scope.products.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
         $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
        } else {
          $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your names list.";
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take it to the "next level", check out xeditable. :)

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-simple

Good luck!

Comment: No need external module for this.

Answer (score 0):

For Edit what you can do:

0.Pass the id on edit click and get data of that id and assign to the same variable you have used for add and hide add button and show update button.

1.Either use the same text field which you are using for add and show/hide button add/update accordingly.

2.You can use separately div which includes one text box and button to update.Show/hide as per you action.